# Import & Export product Brands in Woocommerce 3.x

Tags: php, wordpress, import, woocommerce

Since WooCommerce 3.x there is native Brand support now. However, Brands are not part of the Default **Import/Export** functionality of a Product. I found the documentation on how to add a custom column in **import/export**:

```
/**
 * Add the custom column to the exporter and the exporter column menu.
 *
 * @param array $columns
 * @return array $columns
 */
function add_export_column( $columns ) {

    // column slug => column name
    $columns['custom_column'] = 'Custom Column';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_column_names', 'add_export_column' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_default_columns', 'add_export_column' );

/**
 * Provide the data to be exported for one item in the column.
 *
 * @param mixed $value (default: '')
 * @param WC_Product $product
 * @return mixed $value - Should be in a format that can be output into a text file (string, numeric, etc).
 */
function add_export_data( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'custom_column', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
// Filter you want to hook into will be: 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_{$column_slug}'.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_custom_column', 'add_export_data', 10, 2 );
```

Using `$product->get_meta( 'brands', true, 'edit' );`  did not work out. How can I add Brands to the import/export?

**UPDATE:**
What I did to fix this problem.. - Moved Brands to "Tags" Column - On Admin, Bulk Edit Products by tag, and mark the corresponding Column.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the Ultimate Brands plugin & thought too there must be a way of updating the custom taxonomy values via CSV. I managed to import brand names using the Woocommerce Product CSV Import Suite but have yet to find a way to export via the Woocommerce built in Exporter. Not being a developer, I thought it must be something related to the 'get_terms' function. I've tried many variations with no luck as yet. Was thinking it should look something like this, but not managed to get it to work yet:

```
function add_export_data() {
        $product_id = $post->ID;
        $value =  get_terms($product_id, 'product_brand');      
        return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter you want to hook into will be: **'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_{$column_slug}'.**

So if your custom column name is `product_brand`, then `add_filter` will be like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_product_brand', 'add_export_data', 10, 2 );

function add_export_data( $value, $product ) {
   $value = $product->get_meta( 'product_brand', true, 'edit' );
   return $value;
}
```

If your custom column name is `brands`, then `add_filter` will be like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_brands', 'add_export_data', 10, 2 );

function add_export_data( $value, $product ) {
   $value = $product->get_meta( 'brands', true, 'edit' );
   return $value;
}
```